# Check battery health on iPad like on iPhone

Tags: ipad, battery

How can I check the **battery healthy** of my iPad?

It's not the same as with my iPhone:

- *Settings → Battery → Battery Health*

I haven't the *Battery Health*-Button in *Settings → Battery* on my iPad as I have it on my iPhone.

[image]

How can I check this on my iPad Pro? (Version *13.6*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a program where I can see the battery health from my iPad and also from all others Apple Devices. It names "*iMazing*" and I think very similar to the *Coconut Battery* which is mentioned in another answer.

After [downloading](https://imazing.com/?gclid=CjwKCAjwnK36BRBVEiwAsMT8WGooQH2nr8PjKxc9Tw0AzRfqlnIevjlMRv-Kmz5VVmo1s3n1hHPPsRoCR3sQAvD_BwE) and installing, I must connect my iPad with a USB-lightning cable to my MacBook Pro where I have downloaded *iMazing*.

Then open *iMazing*, and the program will detect your connected iPad, and you must press *trust* on your iPad, that *iMazing* can access to the iPad's information. Then you will see a screen like below:

[image]

On the bottom right (red arrow), click to the battery-logo, and you will become all relevant information to your connected device (in my example from my iPad Pro). But as you can see, you can do a lot other things with this program:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

**Battery Health is currently not available for the iPad.**

According to [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/HT208387),

> For iPhone 6 and later, iOS 11.3 and later add new features to show battery health and recommend if a battery needs to be replaced.

Nowhere on the page does it mention iPad or iPadOS, so unfortunately, at this time, it's limited to iPhones running iOS 11.3 and later.

You may want to submit a feature request with Apple at https://www.apple.com/feedback/ipad.html

Answer (score 6):

If you have a Mac computer you can download and install [coconutBattery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/).

1. Connect your iPad to your Mac with a USB Lightning cable.
2. Open coconutBattery.
3. Click on **iOS Device** on the top of the coconutBattery display on your Mac.

This will give you details about the battery in your iOS device, including battery health.

If you don't have a Mac, go to the App Store and search for "battery". There are many apps that claim to give you info about your battery. These provide different levels of information so you'll have to search for one that provides you with what you want. Many are free so there is plenty to try. I can't really recommend one since I use coconutBattery.

[image: Screenshot of coconutBattery device information for an iPad Air 2]

Comment: +1 for Coconut Battery.  This is a great little utility that provides a lot of battery info.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question imo.  It comes down to “sorta if you have a Mac” and “no if you don’t”. Plus what coconut gives you for free you already get, but if you want the battery health info like the OP asked, you have to spend $10.   I think Apple will update the iPad like they did the Mac and iPhone with this feature for free in the near future.

Comment: The OP asked how to check his battery health.  I gave him 2 ways to do this.  One for if he has a Mac and one way if he doesn’t.  I think I answered his question.

Comment: Once wireless connection is set for iPad on your MBP, coconut battery can read info without the cable. To setup wireless connection, follow https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/ipad/ipadae9bab3e/ipados

Answer (score 3):

Another way, on the iPad itself, is posted at:
https://www.zdnet.com/article/ios-tip-find-out-how-many-times-has-your-iphone-battery-been-recharged/#ftag=CAD-03-10abf5f
Basically, you find "BatteryCycleCount" in log-aggregated-2021-01-16-xxxxxx.ips You have to choose the latest dated file.